# how to check the duplicate filename in asp:fileupload?

Tags: asp.net

i have an updatepanel and inside of it the contenttemplate is an asp:FileUpload..now when i will try to choose the file i want to check the filename in the database..i know my database part but how will i call the function in the server like for asp:TextBox i can use OnTextChanged something like that..but for asp:FileUpload is there anything by which i can check the filename and without clicking the button add?? my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="fileupdatepanel">
                <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="tutorialupload" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnLoad="filename_Changed" />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="f1"></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button ID="addbttu" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="addtutorial_Click" />
```

my aspx.cs code

```
    protected void filename_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string con = " ";
con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
objsqlconn.Open();
string tuname = tutorialupload.PostedFile.FileName;
tuname = tuname.Substring(0, tuname.LastIndexOf("."));
SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("Select tutorialid from tutorialtable where tutorialname='" + tuname + "'", objsqlconn);
SqlDataReader grpIDreader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();
grpIDreader.Read();
if (grpIDreader.HasRows)
{
    f1.Text = "Duplicate filename.Sorry.";
}
else
{
    f1.Text = "";
}

objsqlconn.Close();
}
```

now when i will choose the file..i want to call this function filename_Changed() and it will give me the result whether the filename is present or not..so i want to do it without clicking my the add button??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can detect the change in the selected file name using JavaScript through the FileUpload `onChange` event.

**ASPX Page:** Make sure to set EnablePageMethods = true in the ScriptManager object.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="fileupdatepanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="tutorialupload" runat="server" OnChange="CheckFileName(this)" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="f1"></asp:Label>
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
 <asp:Button ID="addbttu" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="addtutorial_Click" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function CheckFileName(oFile) 
{
    PageMethods.FileNameChecker(oFile.value, OnSucceeded); 
}

function OnSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) 
{   
    lbl = document.getElementById('<%=f1.ClientID %>'); 

    if (methodName == "FileNameChecker") 
    { 
        if (result == true) 
        { 
            lbl.innerHTML = 'Duplicate filename.Sorry.'; 
            lbl.style.color = "red"; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            lbl.innerHTML = ''; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

**C# Code-Behind:** You can call a WebMethod to check if the new selected filename exists in the DB:

You need to reference the following:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

Then add the following method and make sure you put `[WebMethod]` before method declaration:

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool FileNameChecker(string newFileName)
{
    string con = " ";
    con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
    objsqlconn.Open();

    string x = newFileName.Substring(0,newFileName.LastIndexOf("\\"));
    string tuname = newFileName.Substring(newFileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, newFileName.Length - x.Length - 1);
    tuname = tuname.Substring(0, tuname.LastIndexOf("."));

    SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("Select tutorialid from tutorialtable where tutorialname='" + tuname + "'", objsqlconn);
    SqlDataReader grpIDreader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

    grpIDreader.Read();        

    bool found = false;

    if (grpIDreader.HasRows)
        found = true;

    objsqlconn.Close();
    return found;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need ajax if you can do this using JavaScript? Does this not work for you? Please elaborate...

Comment: i need to check the filenames in database..so i need it to use ajax

Comment: This code should do exactly what you need, go back and check, i made changes to the ASPX page, JavaScript, make sure you make all the changes I put. This is an AJAX approach like you requested.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50063/discussion-between-lucidgold-and-setu)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the has file property, when true do you DB check, something like this

```
protected void  UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile) 
        // Before attempting to save the file, do something
    else
      // Notify the user that a file was not uploaded.
      UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
}
```

Comment: is there any way to check the filename from database without clicking the button..i mean when i wll choose the file it will check in the database and show like what we do in OntextChanged for asp:Textbox

Comment: No, cus there needs to be event to trigger , and the textbox events do not trigger in server side asp code, the events are mainly for client side windows development , the only way would be to tie the textbox to a JS event and then check from there, but that's a lot of trouble